# Compute a 3-way merge in Monaco Editor

Tags: diff, monaco-editor

I'm implementing a 3-way merge (currently using OpenBSD's `diff`, `diff3prog`, `ed`) for a client-side LaTeX editor. I would like to make results viewable with Monaco. Is there any way to make Monaco consume an already computed diff? Alternatively, is it possible to get a diff out of Monaco (if it produced a diff with https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/playground.html#creating-the-diffeditor-inline-diff-example)?

I found two related GitHub issues:

- https://github.com/microsoft/monaco-editor/issues/2269
- https://github.com/microsoft/monaco-editor/issues/1463

But maybe someone knows a hack around? It is quite strange if Monaco only allowed to view internally-produced diffs that have no way to materialize.